# How to sync tables between ClickHouse replicas?

Tags: replication, clickhouse

Configuration was 1 shard with 2 replicas (node01 and node02).
I have added new server into cluster configuration: node03

```
<clickhouse>
   <remote_servers>
       <supercluster>
           <shard>
               <internal_replication>true</internal_replication>
               <replica>
                   <host>node01</host>
                   <port>9000</port>
               </replica>
               <replica>
                   <host>node02</host>
                   <port>9000</port>
               </replica>
               <replica>
                   <host>node03</host>
                   <port>9000</port>
               </replica>
           </shard>
       </supercluster>
   </remote_servers>
</clickhouse>
```

After creating new DB and creating respected tables on node03 we may expect new data replication will come to new replica, but how old data from node01[02] might be copied to new replica?
How would you suggest do it to achieve minimal row difference between replicas?

Comment: first thing coming to my mind is to create table as "SELECT * FROM remote()" but wondering if there is better options?